# How to handle internal redirects in iOS5?

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, titanium, nsurlconnection

I'm developing an iPhone app with Titanium Mobile. Now I wanted to link from my app to the App Store with an affiliate link. Of course, this will open Safari first, and then the App Store which is annoying. I found this guide from Apple how to handle redirects internally ([https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa2008/qa1629.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20101023135529/http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa2008/qa1629.html)). As I'm using Titanium, I thought I'll just implement a native module and use it from Titanium then.

So far so good, but I can't get it working. Here's what I have so far (I do not know Objective-C, so some of this might be stupid):

DeCompendiiReferralDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DeCompendiiReferralDelegate : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>

@property (retain) NSURL* iTunesURL;

-(void)openReferralUrl:(NSURL *)referralURL;

@end
```

DeCompendiiReferralDelegate.m

```
#import "DeCompendiiReferralDelegate.h"

@implementation DeCompendiiReferralDelegate

@synthesize iTunesURL;

- (void)openReferralUrl:(NSURL *)referralURL {
    NSURLConnection *con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:referralURL] delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
    [con release];
}

- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    self.iTunesURL = [response URL];
    if( [self.iTunesURL.host hasSuffix:@"itunes.apple.com"])
    {
        [connection cancel];
        [self connectionDidFinishLoading:connection];
        return nil;
    }
    else
    {
        return request;
    }
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {    
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:self.iTunesURL];
}

@end
```

I call this code from DeCompendiiReferralModule.m. Debugging shows that openReferralUrl is called, but the URL is never opened. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Just to make sure I'm not doing something stupid in setting this up, here's how I call this code:

```
DeCompendiiReferralDelegate *referralDelegate = [[DeCompendiiReferralDelegate alloc] init];
[referralDelegate openReferralUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You `release` your connection right away. You should do that only after the connection finishes.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I just copied the code from the Apple guide though, and they release the connection right away. I removed the line and tried again, but nothing changes ...

Comment: So do some logging in `connectionDidFinishLoading` and see if you even get there. Also, you should not call `connectionDidFinishLoading` yourself...

Comment: I just left out the logging statements for the code example. I have logging statements all over the place. connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse and connectionDidFinishLoading never get called.

Comment: @Mundi The `NSURLConnection` returns itself once it starts the request, and his `NSURLConnection` start immediately so its safe to release if you just want to listen to the delegate methods.

Comment: Then maybe you did not set your delegate protocol as `< NSURLConnectionDelegate>` properly in the `@interface` declaration...